# How to change the position of a video using MediaElement in Windows8?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, mediaelement

Currently I am doing this in my code,

```
 playbackElement1.AutoPlay = true;
 playbackElement1.SetSource(stream, this.m_recordStorageFile.FileType);
 playbackElement1.Position = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 5000);
 playbackElement1.Play();
```

It doesn't work, checking for a video longer than 5 secs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two problems. First, [MediaElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement) can only set the position once the media is loaded, determined by handling the [MediaOpened](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.mediaopened.aspx) event. Secondly, not all media is seekable. Check by calling [CanSeek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.canseek.aspx). Use something like:

```
playbackElement1.AutoPlay = true;
// Will fire after the media has loaded
playbackElement1.MediaOpened += (source, args) =>
{
    MediaElement player = (MediaElement) source;
    if (player.CanSeek)
    {
        player.Position = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 5000);   
    }
}                     
playbackElement1.SetSource(stream, this.m_recordStorageFile.FileType);
```

Once loaded, use the [NaturalDuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.naturalduration.aspx) property to see the length of the media, converting it to a TimeSpan using [HasTimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.duration.hastimespan.aspx) and [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.duration.timespan.aspx) properties if needed.

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, you will need to add a Slider underneath the MediaElement just like in any video player...
- the Slider will update the player current position
- the Timer will update the slider every 300 millisecond with the current player position

Code:

```
<Slider x:Name="videoSlider" Thumb.DragStarted="videoSlider_DragStarted" Thumb.DragCompleted="videoSlider_DragCompleted" Margin="10,0,10,30" Height="18" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>

<MediaElement x:Name="videoPlayer" Margin="4,59,152,53" Volume=".5" MediaOpened="videoPlayer_MediaOpened">
```

[This is picture for the Media-Element with the Slider][1]

Now we have a media element and a slider... Next: C# Code :)

```
         public partial class MainWindow : Window
         {  
               bool isSeekingMedia = false;
               DispatcherTimer seeker;   // the timer to update the Slider
               public MainWindow()
               {
                    InitializeComponent();
                    player = new MediaPLayer();
                    IsPlaying(false);
                    seeker = new DispatcherTimer();
                    seeker.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200);
                    seeker.Tick += Seeker_Tick;
        }
    ///Seeker_Tick will update the Slider position while the video is playing
                private void Seeker_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        MediatimeCounter.Content = String.Format("{0:hh}:{0:mm}:{0:ss}/{1:hh}:{1:mm}:{1:ss}", videoPlayer.Position, videoPlayer.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan);
                        if (!isSeekingMedia)
                        {
                            videoSlider.Value = videoPlayer.Position.TotalSeconds;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex) { }
                }


//This code is going to set Seeking to true to avoid playing the video if the user is changing the slider position... it kinda causes a performance issue.. so it's better to update the video position once the slider dragging event is completed.
private void videoSlider_DragStarted(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        isSeekingMedia = true;
    }

//and this code is to update the video position based on the slider value.
private void videoSlider_DragCompleted(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (videoPlayer.Source != null)
        {
            isSeekingMedia = false;
            this.videoPlayer = player.SeekVideo(videoPlayer, videoSlider.Value);
        }
    }
```

[image]